# Is it okay to do the RecyclerView setAdapter() several times?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

When use `RecyclerView`, Does it matter how many times `setAdapter()` has been used?

Or should `setAdapter` be used only once?

and Is it okay to use `setAdapter` after adding items to the `adpater`?

Or should the `setAdapter` work before adding items to the `adapter`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General practise is to call `RecyclerView::setAdapter` once per instantiation of the `RecyclerView` then use the `RecyclerView.Adapter<VH>` for updating the underlying `List<T>` data set then calling methods like `Adapter::notifyDatasetChanged`.

`Recyclerview.Adapter` also allows updating individual rows through other methods : https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter

More modern techniques include `DiffUtil` or `AsyncListDiffer` which uses `DiffUtil` or manual implementations to abstract working out individual row changes between data set updates.  This is the most efficient mechanism as it only needs to "rebind" changed data on screen, rather than rebinding all views.

If you intend to change the type `T` of the underlying data set then you can call `RecyclerView::setAdapter` more than once, as you are fundamentally changing the adapter data set type.  This however is an edge case.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are switching different adapters on the same RecyclerView, it's recommended you call setAdapter once (even with an empty list of elements). Then, when you update the list of elements, you can call adapter methods like notifyDataSetChanged and other similar methods.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you are setting the same adapter instance multiple times just to refresh then, please take a look at [RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyDataSetChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifydatasetchanged)

A better approach would be 'setAdapter work before adding items to the adapter' and then you can add, remove, and modify adapter data items. Then you can notify the adapter.